# unknown type yypcontext_t in bison

Tags: c, bison

I've been working with bison this last week and I wanted to make my parser produce some diagnostically, beautiful message that a person would understand.

From this [GNU website](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Syntax-Error-Reporting-Function.html), I started declaring the function `int yyreport_syntax_error (const yypcontext_t *ctx)` in my `yacc.y` file like this:

```
%{
/* some code above*/
extern int yyreport_syntax_error (const yypcontext_t *ctx);
%}
```

Ran bison with the command `bison -d yacc.y`, compiled it together with my lex.yy.c, and then clang; my compiler, greeted me happily with an error:

```
yacc.y:17:36: error: unknown type name 'yypcontext_t'
extern yyreport_syntax_error(const yypcontext_t *yyctx);
                                   ^
yacc.y:17:8: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'
      [-Wimplicit-int]
extern yyreport_syntax_error(const yypcontext_t *yyctx);
~~~~~~ ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

Yes, clang reported that there's no type named 'yypcontext_t'.

Did I forgot to include a bison library or explicitly typedef it? I don't think so, because none of it was written in the website.

If you need elaboration, I would gladly do so.

Bison version 3.6.3

**MWE**: test.y

```
%define parse.error custom

%{
#include <stdio.h>

extern FILE *yyin;
extern int yylex();
extern int yyreport_syntax_error(const yypcontext_t *yyctx);

%}

%token SP

%%

file : SP
     ;

%%

int main(){
   yyparse();
   return 0;
}
```

After running `bison -d test.y`, execute `gcc -c test.tab.c`

Comment: Did you put `%define parse.error custom` into your prologue, as that documentation requires?

Comment: @rici Absolutely! At the very top before %{ %} begins. Does your bison works?

Comment: It's hard to know unless you provide a (hopefully small) example of the file you are attempting to process with bison. (No need for the flex file.)

Comment: @rici Hi! I added an MWE.

Comment: Thanks! That make things much easier to answer. (Meanwhile, I installed v3.6.3 for testing so I could verify the problems with your file.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yypcontext_t` is not exported in the bison-generated headers, so you're not going to be able to define your `yyreport_syntax_error` function in a different translation unit. It will have to go in your `.y` file, and it will have to be placed at the end, after the second `%%`.

There's no point in forward declaring `yyreport_syntax_error`, since the bison-generated parser includes a forward declaration. But note that the declaration is

```
static int
yyreport_syntax_error (const yypcontext_t *yyctx);
```

further confirming that the expectation is that `yyreport_syntax_error` be defined in the `.y` file itself.

**Note**: I reported this as a documentation bug (https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bison/2020-06/msg00054.html), since it seems to me that the documentation really should mention this fact. (And apparently it will in some upcoming release.)

Comment: @Spade000: I reported this issue as a documentation bug. It seems to me that it is not obvious from the documentation (although it must be that way since `yyreport_syntax_error` cannot work without calling other `static` internal functions), so I suggested adding a note into the docs.

Comment: That would be helpful to others who's also implementing this.

Comment: @Spade000: The example in the bison manual (and in the `examples/c/bistromathic` directory in the distribution) is probably a useful guide. At least, it works as advertised :-)

Comment: The examples are not just part of the tarball, there are also part of the standard installation (typically in `/usr/local/share/doc/bison/examples`).

Comment: @akim: depending on the packager, no? Although I see that Debian is now including the examples, since last June. They are certainly not in `/usr/local/share/doc/bison/examples` on my standard (but somewhat outdated) Ubuntu install, but perhaps if I update my system they will appear.

Comment: I don't know what Debian/Ubuntu do.  On MacPorts, they do it right.  Maybe in the "doc" packages?  But at least the tarball, when it installs itself, does install the examples, and their Makefiles.  I consider it a bug if packagers don't install these examples (possibly in doc subpackages).

Comment: `/usr/local` is the default with `./configure`, but package managers often install elsewhere.  `/opt/local` for MacPorts, and I guess `/usr` for Debian/Ubuntu.  So I would expect the examples to be in `/usr/share/doc/bison/examples`.

Comment: @akim: until a year ago, the examples were simply not included in the Debian packages. Reading between lines, I suspect there was some uncertainty about whether they conformed with Debian's "free software" requirements. I don't know if you (or some bisonista) negotiated with them, or whether they had a spontaneous change of heart, but the packaging policy changed in June 2019. That didn't make the examples show up on my laptop because I'm still using an old base version which works with my wireless hardware. Anyway, all is good now (except the wireless support).

Comment: @rici Thanks for tracking this down.  Actually, I don't remember if I reported this to the Debian maintainer, but I can't find that in my mail history.  Wrt the license, it is true the files don't have the usual license comment on the top.  I simply forgot about that.  I'll ask what others think we should do, and clarify this.  Thanks again!